# Linking circles to anchors

Tags: d3.js

I created anchors in a table, inserting. `<tr id="link_i>` for each line.
the json contains a lot of  `"link":"#link_i`
My code is below :
...

```
circles
.attr("xlink:href",function(d) { return d.link; })
.on("mouseover",function(d,i){ tooltip.style("visibility","visible");return tooltip.text(d.title);})
.on("mouseout",function(){return tooltip.style("visibility","hidden");})

...
```

The svg graph with a lot of circles works fine, showing each specific "title" when the mouse is over the different circles, but when I click on any circle, the link doesn't move the page down to the specified anchor ...
Does anyone has an idea ?

Yves

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle or something comparable?!

Comment: I finally find the good way, listening a comment from Mr Fegur on a previous post, using .on("click",function(d) {document.location=d.link;})